# Can you connect BH1790GLC and TMP117 sensors to an Arduino board?

Tags: sensors, communication, temperature-sensor

I would like to use those two components for an upcoming project :

- [BH1790GLC heart rate sensor](https://www.rohm.com/datasheet/BH1790GLC)
- [TMP117 temperature sensor](http://www.ti.com/product/TMP117)

I especially like the fact that they’re so tiny.

Could I connect them directly to an Arduino board or some other well-known microcontroller ?

Comment: Both of those sensors use I2C to communicate, so yes you can connect them to Arduino. but you gonna need a library and if the library doesn't exist you probably have lots of coding ahead of you. good luck. [TMP117 library](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+TMP117+library)

Comment: Actually there are Arduino libraries available online for both of these sensors, which is one of the reasons why I chose them

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sensors will work with microcontroller(s). What you look for is the **interface** they use. In this case it is **I<sup>2</sup>C** interface. Be careful thou: You have to check voltage levels your microcontroller works with and selected sensor voltage level. Some of the Arduino works with 5V levels and some sensors may accept max of 3.3V or 4.5V on I<sup>2</sup>C pins. This is why you would need either:

- Choose 3V powered microcontroller
- Use 5V powered microcontroller (like Arduino Uno) and voltage level converter

Also worth to note that these two sensors would need some additional circuitry to work with your microcontroller. Before any commitment I would try to find a development board (a board with mentioned circuitry with easy to acces pins for providing necessary signals/voltages/ground/etc).
Good luck!